# Download source code files using Git Hub developer API

Tags: github-api

Using the [Github developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/), is it possible to download the latest source code files of a particular Github repository?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the [Get archive link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

For example:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/tarball > octokit.tar.gz
```

That example does not specify a ref, which means by default, it will be the repository’s default branch (usually `master`)